《Do you have any good suggestions for beginners entering blockchain technology?》
"Everyone, I've been self-studying blockchain knowledge recently. Although I have some experience with BIT, ETH, TRX wallet knowledge, as well as ETF, perpetual contract, and instant contract transactions on exchanges, and have implemented K-line charts using HTX (Huobi)'s WSS, I've realized that blockchain or exchange businesses involve much more than this. Therefore, I hope to follow the footsteps of the experts in this forum and would appreciate any advice you can offer. Thank you!"
各位，我最近自学区块知识，虽然说接触过BIT,ETH,TRX钱包知识，以及交易所的ETF、永续合约、秒合约的业务交易，K线是拿htx(火币)的wss来实现的，琢磨了一段时间发现区块或者交易所业务不止这些，所以我想在次论坛中跟紧大佬门的脚步，希望各位能提提意见，感谢！

Generally questions that will result in opinion based answers are not allowed. Do you think you could target your question to include in which area you need guidance, and exactly what type of expertise you are looking for. What is the end goal, where do you want to end up? Much love.

If you are interested in developing on Ethereum and zkSync , cyfrin Updraft is a good start. I have been learning on their platform for the past 2 days and its amazing with the resource.

Great, thank you very much. Thank you for providing valuable advice to me, who has a weak foundation. I wish you peace and happiness every day
太好了，非常感谢，感谢您对基础薄弱的我提供宝贵的建议，祝您平平安安，开开心心的度过每一天
